# Why is this Java static field null?

Tags: java

```
public class StaticTest {

    private static String a;
    private static String b = "this is " + a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = "test";

        System.out.println(b); // prints "this is null"
    }

}
```

I'm confused about `b`'s value. I think the result should be "this is test", but the result is "this is null". Why?

Comment: Static field was initialized during class load. At this moment `a` was `null`.

Answer (score 7):

Others have explained why it works the way it does.

However, there are ways to to have the value calculated when you reference it.

```
private static String a;
private static Supplier<String> bSupplier = ()->"this is " + a;

public static void main(String[] args){
    a = "test";
    System.out.println(bSupplier.get()); //Prints "this is a test"
}
```

When you call `bSupplier.get()` the value is calculated. If you change the value of `a`, and call it again, the value will reflect the new value.

This is not something you should be doing often, but is useful to know.

Answer (score 4):

You add String a to string b but string a is not yet defined.you should add it to string b after you define it.

```
private static String a = "test";
private static String b = "this is a " + a;
public static void main(String [] args){
  System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: but I wish change b when a changes. I want this effect. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You did

```
private static String a;
private static String b = "this is " + a;
```

At this point, `a` was `null`. Therefore, the `String` `b` became

```
this is null
```

Now, any changes in `a` wouldn't reflect on `b`. Therefore, this result. For the expected result, do

```
private String a = "test";
private String b = "this is " + a;
```

Answer (score 3):

> but I wish change b when a changes. I want this effect. What should I
>   do?

Static fields are initialized when the class is loaded. 
So in a method of the class, you cannot modify the content of the static field by changing simply the value of one of the variable used to value this field during its initializing.

In your case using static field for `b` doesn't address your need.
`b` should be rather a static method `getB()` that returns a `String` instance according to the current `a` value at the time where it is invoked:

```
public class StaticTest {

    private static String a;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a = "test";    
        System.out.println(getB());
    }

    private static String getB(){
       return "this is " + a;    
    } 
}
```

PS : It is a close enough way from the  Steven Lowes's answer that is specific to Java 8.

Comment: can't we append like, with a reference ? I mean, for now I understand that `+` or `.concat`, just copies `chars` at the end of the `String`. What if we want to attach a reference, possibly of `StringBuilder`, and then mutate its contents, and see the change in the orignal `String`. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Shashwat Strings are immutable. Any `String` appended to the `StringBuilder` cannot not have side effect on other `String` instances.

Answer (score 3):

When classloader loads a class into JVM, it does it in three phases

1.) Load

2.) Link 
(Which is further divided into three steps i.e. 
(a.) verify, (b.) prepare, (c.) resolve)

3.) Initialize

So during prepare (Link) phase classloader initialize the static variables (not instance) and sets them to their default initial values (not actual value), and for the string it is null.

Now During Initialize phase static variables are assigned their actual value and still `a` is `null`. Because `main` method will be run after this step.

So inside main `a` is assigned value `"test"` and `b` is already assigned by classloader during initialization when `a` was null, so that is the reason String `b` has strange output.

Answer (score 1):

So, to start out, when you run your program, those static fields are set before your main method is run, in the order that they are defined, so `a` gets set to `null`, and `b` gets set to `"this is null"`, and then your main method is run, making `a` have a value of `"test"`.

What Java does when it sees

```
private static String b = "this is" + a;
```

Is takes `"this is"` and attaches the **value** of `a` onto it. If `a`'s value changes later, `b`'s value won't, because `b` doesn't store a link to the variable `a`, it just stores the value it was assigned.